# "Run as Administrator" vs "Run (As Admin!)"

Tags: windows-10, administrator

What is the difference between "Run as Administrator" and "Run (As Admin!)"?

[image]

Comment: If you find out what this was, an update could be nice!

Comment: Does that appear in the context menus of all executables, or just one particular program?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I'm behind a work firewall which strips out imgur links, so I didn't see it!

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu, all executables.

Comment: Go to each one path, and send to virustotal.com to check for viruses.

Answer (score 110):

"Run as administrator" appears to be a normal Windows 10 context menu entry.

"Run (As Admin!)" is very much not a normal entry - Microsoft does not use exclamation points in commands like that. Whatever it is, it's a third party, and I would suggest you don't use it. It's entirely possible it's meant to steal account credentials. You should scour your system, figure out where it came from, and get rid of it if you can't verify it is benign.

Comment: Indeed, even without prior knowledge of this context menu, it is obvious from the highly unexpected exclamation mark that this isn't a native Windows menu item. In addition, the capitalization also violates the [Microsoft Windows user interface guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/text-ui), since menu items should use sentence-style capitalization, not title-style capitalization (like in the title bar).

Comment: You may be able to find what program added the context entry by searching for "As Admin!" in regedit.

Comment: As a side-not, exclamation-mark (!) is/was sometimes used in menu-bar/menus to show that the entry was an action, and wouldn't, for example, open a menu.  One example was the "Run!" entry in the menu-bar of old Borland C++ (for DOS) - this ran the program directly, while the other entries opened (drop-down) menus and dialogues.  BTW, similarly in menus, an arrow (>) denoted a sub-menu, while an eclipse (...) denoted a dialogue.

Comment: @BaardKopperud: But that practice has not been part of the Windows UI guidelines for at least 25-30 years. It is highly unexpected in this world.

Answer (score 36):

> *What is the difference between Run as Administrator vs Run (As Admin!)?*

- You need to check the Windows registry entries to find out what **Run (as Admin!)** and what it does by checking the command line you have there.

Look in these keys.

```bat
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\Run

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\ContextMenus\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\
```

Call some support to remove/delete this key, *do not* try by your self, learn first how to backup/restore windows register before try to learn how to delete anything...

Save this code below as query_reg.cmd and run it; this will make a query on each key (also sub keys),

Thus, it will be possible to compare the commands / values ​​of the normal / standard Windows entry and this strange one in its context menu.

```bat
@echo off 

cd.>"%temp%\cmd_from_keys.log"

for %%k in ("HKCR\Directory\shell","HKCR\Directory\shell\runas","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\*",^
    "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory","HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications") do echo/%%~k && (
            for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%reg.exe query %%k /s /f "Admin"') do (
               echo/%%i >>"%temp%\cmd_from_keys.log" && echo/%%i
               ))
start "Reg Querys" notepad.exe "%temp%\cmd_from_keys.log"
```

Comment: Using Autoruns from Sysinternals is a nice GUI tool to do what's been outlined here.

Comment: @user2064000 for sure it is, but also is easy to de sable something that can possible crash windows boot/startup.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe It wasn't you who broke the startup of that computer over there by editing the registry?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere I disabled some services or some important loading (dll / exe) using autoruns, and the result was that Windows did not start after that. And this thought about interrupting / stopping a viral reinfection cycle, suspending one of the files / instructions on loading, obviously, I was very wrong.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe So it was you. I think you need a new name! :)

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere Let's agree not to tell anyone, okay? I did this on my computer with my computer!!

Comment: Luckily when I was learning how to use autoruns, I had windows XP so all it took was pressing F8 during startup to choose "last restore point" to rollback my changes. Wish windows was still so easy to use.